# Shipping dependencies (dynamic libraries) with an executable build under Mac OS with Crystal-lang

Tags: shell, macos

I am looking for a way to ship dependencies (dynamic libraries) with an executable build under Mac OS with Crystal-lang, is there a way to improve on:

- It seems to works, but it is a bit of a hack.

````
# The name of the executable
app=$1

# Create a directory to hold the app and dependencies
mkdir -p "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS"
mkdir -p "MyApp.app/Contents/libs"

# Copy the app into the MacOS directory
cp $app "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/"

# Get the dependencies
dependencies=$(otool -L $app | awk 'NR>1{print $1}')

# Copy the dependencies into the libs directory and rename them
for dep in $dependencies; do
  dep_name=$(basename $dep)
  cp $dep "MyApp.app/Contents/libs/$dep_name"
  install_name_tool -change $dep "@executable_path/../libs/$dep_name" "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/$app"
done

# Create a script to set the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable
cat > "MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp" << EOF
#!/bin/sh
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:\$(cd \$(dirname \$0) && pwd)/../libs
$PWD/$app
EOF

```
````

Comment: Imagine you decide to rename the folder "Contents", and/or the folder "MyApp.app". In how many places do you need to replace text? Do you think that's a good approach, or is it error-prone?

Comment: @BCdotWEB you could pass said names as options to the script (just like the app name). In this case, renaming said items is just a matter of re-running the script with the new values.

Comment: The title should be what the code does, not what your question is. Thanks.